# Open Georeferencer with layer path in PyQGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, interface

I develop a QGIS plugin that includes a step of georeferencing. I want to open the Georeferencer from QGIS and to load an image with its path when I click on a PushButton.

I found this topic : [Open Georeferencer and load raster at startup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244419/open-georeferencer-and-load-raster-at-startup)

which seemed to conclude that it's not possible to pass an argument when opening the Georeferencer (and the proposed code doesn't really work for me) :

```
self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, "&Georeferencer").trigger()
for x in self.iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QMainWindow):
    if x.objectName() == 'QgsGeorefPluginGuiBase':
        for y in x.children():
            if 'mActionOpenRaster' in y.objectName():
                y.trigger()
```

I got the following error :
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'trigger'` so `"&Georeferencer"` surely isn't the good attribute to open it.

It's been answered for QGIS 2. Is there any way to access Georeferencer window from QGIS 3 interface and pass an image as input?

I looked at Processing toolbox and the Georeferencer is not part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open Georeferencer window in QGIS 3:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction, 'mActionShowGeoreferencer')[0].trigger()
```

To open "Open Raster" dialog

```
iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction, 'mActionOpenRaster')[0].trigger()
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could directly open a raster with its filepath ?

Comment: I tried, but I couldnt find a way.

Comment: Is there a way to run georefencer without interface ? I mean, with all parameters for the transformation, with the layer and the GCP file ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/116672/29431

Comment: your solution works under unix but I get an error with QGIS 3.4 on Windows. The mActionShowGeoreferencer action is not recognized. On this version, Georeferencer is still a plugin to install manually. Is there a link with it ?

Comment: Then it is time to update. I tested it in QGIS 3.22.